# android RatingBar touch move changed listener

Tags: android

I can't catch an event when the RatingBar stars change.
I used `setOnRatingBarChangeListener`, but in this case I catch the rate of my `RatingBar` only on `Action_UP`.

I want to make so:

> when rate==1 star's color is color1,
>   when rate==2 stars' color is color2,
>   when rate==3 stars' color is color3,
>   when rate==4 stars' color is color4,
>   when rate==5 stars' color is color5.

It should change, when I touch `Action_MOVE`.

Answer (score 0):

In rating bar you can directly find the no of rating by this listener in rating string you can get no of the rating.

```
 ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
                                    boolean fromUser) {

            ratings = String.valueOf(rating);

        }
    });
```

Comment: I did it. I want get rate when TOUCH MOVE and DOWN and UP, not only when TOUCH UP

Answer (score 0):

#1 reference your RatingBar

```
val rating = findViewById(R.id.ratingbar)
```

#2 implement the interface

```
View.OnTouchListener
rating.setOnTouchListener(this)
```

#3 within the implementation do your logic like:

```
override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {

        val rating = mRatingBar.rating
        // Implement your logic
        return false
    }
```